# How to add fully custom service worker in React?

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

I'm new in service workers and i want to add my custom service worker in react `not using their boilerplate SW from create react app` so, How can i do that? and what are the steps that i need to do that.

Comment: why don't you want to use default service worker and update it to your needs?

Comment: @PompolutZ u mean that i can delete the code inside the default sw and write my own?
`Also i feel like i learned sw and there is another person do it for me, i really need to practice  with my own configuration and learn from my mistakes that's all`

Comment: You are totally free to delete one created for you and start from scratch, but because you ask where to start I assume, its better not to, but rather modify existing one to your cause.

Comment: @PompolutZ Appreciated,one more question, if i deleted the created one and i made my own is there is an additional setup to make the project knows that this is the new one ? or should it work fine without any setup \

Comment: No, service worker are just a part of "convention" called PWA, which basically says that if you website has a service worker and manifest file in your public directory, written in a correct way, then browser will know about them and would allow user to "install" the website and run it like native app.